# How to change my target in PC?

Tags: tales-of-zestiria

I'am new to tales of zestiria and I can't change my target when multiple enemy comes. So, how can I change my target in PC?

Comment: Using an Xbox pad on PC it's hold RB

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change and configure what you'd like the controls to be, just go to the main menu and you'll find keybindings at Controls Settings. If you want to get to the battle keybindings, just change the configuration option to battle. Then you should be able to adjust the targeting option to your liking.